# Calculate the general solution and the specific solution of the following differential equation: $(3y - 1)^2) (y'^2) = 4y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Calculate the general solution and the specific solution of the following differential equation: $(3y - 1)^2  (y')^2 = 4y.$

The general solution is $(x + C)^2 = y(y - 1)^2$ and the specific is $y = 0$.

I have tried rewriting it like $y' = \dfrac{2y}{3y + 1}$ but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

You have got $\displaystyle y'=\frac{2\sqrt y}{3y-1}$

Therefore $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2\sqrt y}{3y-1}$

$\displaystyle\implies\int \frac{3y-1}{2\sqrt y}dy=\int dx$

$\implies\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}\int\sqrt y-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}=x+C$

$\implies \displaystyle y^{\frac{3}{2}}-y^{\frac{1}{2}}=x+C$

Squaring both sides we get

$y^3+y-2y^2=(x+C)^2\implies y(y-1)^2=(x+C)^2$

Comment: And since you divided by $y-0$ in the beginning, you might have excluded the possible singular solution $y\equiv 0$. We can easily verify that $y\equiv 0$ satisfies the original DE and is not included in the general solution, hence $y\equiv 0$ is the singular solution.